# .sql database import not working. (stored procedure error)

Tags: mariadb

I am new to MySQL.
I want to import the database from .sql file.
Tables are imported successfully.

but it gives the below error regarding procedures :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dev`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_PlaceBet`(
    IN `pLogInId` INT,
    IN `pUserId` INT,
    IN `pParantId` INT,
    IN `pMatchId` INT,
    IN `pSelectionId` INT,
    IN `pStack` INT,
    IN `pMarketId` VARCHAR(100),
    IN `pselectionName` VARCHAR(100),
    IN `pMstDate` DATETIME,
    IN `pOdds` DECIMAL(10, 2),
    IN `pP_L` DECIMAL(10, 2),
    IN `pisBack` INT,
    IN `pIsMatched` INT,
    IN `pNarration` VARCHAR(200),
    IN `pdeviceInfo` VARCHAR(100),
    IN `pIP_ADDESSS` VARCHAR(100),
    IN `pInPlayStack` INT,
    IN `pIsApp` INT,
    IN `pType` VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE LID INTEGER;
    DECLARE lCtr integer;
    DECLARE resultV INT;
    DECLARE retMess VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE checkBal decimal(50, 2);
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      set resultV = -1;
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
      SET retMess = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
      ROLLBACK;
      [...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'STACKED DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL...' at line 31
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to PHP? And why have you tagged it with both MySQL and MariaDB? Which is it?

Comment: show us the **complete** procedure please

Comment: Removed all irrelevant tags. It is clear from the error message that the OP uses mariadb. The script would work fine on mysql, therefore mysql tag is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using mariadb, not mysql. If you check out the error message, it tells you to fefer to the mariadb manual.

Mariadb's [get diagnostics](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/get-diagnostics/) statement does not have `stacked` option, so you must remove it if you want to use the code in a mariadb environment or you need to migrate to a proper mysql server.

Comment: Thanks, Shadow!
So, How can I resolve it?
Maybe import using MySQL Workbench or another option?

Comment: @JIGNESHPATEL I did provide you the two possible ways of resolving the issue: remove the stacked keyword or use mysql as opposed to mariadb.